# ADODB.Recordset locking my local source file

Tags: adodb

I'm using local Excel file on my PC as database. My Add-in pulls data from this database file to new resulting excel files. When my add-in open an ADODB connection and Recordset, it automatically lock source db file for me (I can open it in read-only mode). It's not a big deal, but I'm curious why. Even if I open the Recordset with optimistic lock, it still locks the file to read-only. Is it supposed to be this way? (and, my add-in is not modifying any data, it's not suppose to)

```
sConnectionStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sDBFile & _
                 ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

DBConnection.Open sConnectionStr
    
rs.Open sQuery, DBConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

P. S. And one more quick question: how to SELECT * from specific table, not the whole Sheet? Currently I'm getting the whole sheet:

```
sQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Existing$]"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to close connection to release filehandle.

Comment: `how to SELECT * from specific table, not the whole Sheet?` What you mean table ? I ask as for EXCEL fill Table mean the same as Sheet

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. Additionally, if the recordset is holding "readonly" data, then you need to `Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing` in order to keep the recordset functional after closing the connection to release the locked file.

Comment: Do you mean that closing connection was not enough, and you must firstly release reference to `Connection`  in your `Recordset` object ?
Or you just do not want to close `Connection` but only release `Recordest` ?

Comment: My addin was returning a `Recordset` and keeping the connection open, which locked the "database" file. What you suggested did release the file lock, but the returned `Recordset` became invalid. I suppose I could (or maybe should?) close the `Connection` after using the `Recordset`, but I didn't want to leave this responsibility to the caller. Releasing the reference to the `Connection` in the `Recordset` object before returning it did the trick. (I have little knowledge in this subject, so maybe I'm doing it "the wrong way" :P)